# Indexing matrices when some elements of the selector are missing (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, indexing

When some elements of a vector used for row-indexing a `matrix` or a `data.frame` are missing `NA` in `R`, the indexing operation has results that I find unexpected.

```
m      = matrix(1:15,ncol = 3)
m[1,1] = NA
m[m[,1] < 4 ,]
```

Gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
```

While I would have expected

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    4   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
```

One option seems to be

```
m[m[,1] < 4 | is.na(m[,1]) ,]
```

But I find this unhandy. It often happens to me that I lose data by mistake when indexing matrices and data.frames that contains missings. Is there an easier and safer way to reach the desired result?

Comment: Perhaps `m[m[,1] %in% c(NA, 1:3),]`

Comment: The result of  `m[,1] < 4` is `NA  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`. You are using the result as index for the rows in `m[m[,1] < 4 ,]`

Comment: @jogo yes but I would expect it to leave the row untouched when the results is `NA`. So I wonder if there is a safer way of subsetting.

Comment: @akrun no this does not involve a logical rule anymore (`<4`).

Comment: @tomka The logic of `R` is: if you operate with the value `NA` then the result is `NA`. In your case you are using the function `'['`, e.g. `'['(m, 3, 2)`

Comment: You could create a function like `'%<NA%' <- function(x, val) x < val | is.na(x);  m[,1] %<NA% 4#
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: *"I would expect it to leave the row untouched when the results is NA"* - I would argue that "leaving the row untouched" is exactly what you're getting! The problem is that you want to touch/include the `NA` result as if it were `TRUE`.

Comment: Another function alternative: `true.na = function(x) {x | is.na(x)}`, then you could use `m[true.na(m[,1] < 4 ), ]`

Comment: @Gregor Okay, so it seems I have to solve this problem myself and there is not a built in way to do this. It is a bit surpring; not even `base::subset` has an according option.